# Naming the legend entry in Gnuplot, while plotting from a data file

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, plot, gnuplot

I am plotting a data file with six columns in gnuplot. If the plot of column 2 against column 1 is x(t), I want that line in the legend something like `x(t)`, NOT what I currently get for column two against column one, `"trial.dat" u 1:2`.

How would I name the legend line, then?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You use the `title` keyword in the plot line:

```
plot 'trial.dat' u 1:2 title "x(t)"
```

You can also get rid of the legend entry all together by using `notitle`.